# How can I tell when my android app is too big, and where can I find out how to progress to another app?

Tags: android, eclipse, performance

I was told by the instructor in my app-development course last Spring to "keep it small and simple," but I'm not sure how much of that was b/c a semester is short. 
   I'm trying to make an app to teach users how to subtract positive and negative integers. It has six activities and four custom Views for number lines, and my computer gets incredibly slow now.  When I deleted an activity (and its related layouts, etc) things ran faster.  However, it might be Eclipse that's slow, and not the app. 
    I could break the app into two apps, but I'm not finding (maybe because I'm not using the right search terms) a way to link to the "next app" when the user is ready.
    Since I'd like to make a prequel app with adding positive and negative integers, I need to address this at some point anyway.

Comment: 6 activities seems too much for your purpose...did you try to contact your instructor?

Comment: What does my instructor have to do with how many activities are too many?  Are you questioning the activities in the app, or the activiites to demonstrate/interact to learn about integers?

Comment: Okay, took too long to edit that.. 
   Yes, I tried to contact the instructor; he again recanted that keeping things simple was good... but was distracted and busy, so I didn't really get to figure out whether he thought it was because I was a novice or because it was something the app couldn't handle.

Comment: Removing an activity from an app shouldn't speed up its execution much, maybe it's just the placebo effect? Anyway, it sounds like you're using the emulator and not an actual device, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. I realize that slows everything down, but (mistakenly?) thought it worth asking.  I am trying to learn and (mistakenly?) thought folks here might have answers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that asking how many activities would affect performance isn't "off topic, " so I'll assume there's some other issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If taking away an activity shouldn't speed things up then I'm inferring that adding them shouldn't be slowing things down.  (Also inferring that I've gotten to the place where my questions aren't already on SO, but they're not the kind that SO knows the answers too...)